# Есть ли в этом предложении тавтология?

Tags: тавтология

***Душно, окно не открыл, я-то открыл.***

В предложении повторяется глагол, можно ли это считать тавтологией?

Answer (score 1):

(1) ***ДУшно*** – (2) ***окнО не открыл***, (3) ***я-то открыл***.

Интересный вопрос.

**Запись устной речи** – это не такая простая вещь, а иногда задача повышенной сложности, то есть **нестандартная** задача. Здесь требуется не только знание правил, но и умение их применить, ведь разговорная речь с **упрощенным** синтаксисом в то же время очень эмоциональна и выразительна.

**Это бессоюзное сложное  предложение**, состоящее их трех простых. Предложения  1 и 2  связывает разделительная интонация, обозначенная тире.  Запятая обозначает присоединительную интонацию, выражающую продолжение речи (значение распространения).

Смысл такой: *Тебе душно, потому что ты окно не открыл, вот я же его открыл, в отличие о тебя.*  Становится очевидным, что здесь **нет тавтологии,** хотя глагол повторяется.

Comment: Спасибо за понимание.